# How to clean corpora from words with fourfold repeated letters?

Tags: r, text-mining

On inspecting a term-document matrix created with `TermDocumentMatrix` of the `tm` library (of Twitter data), I find that many words are of the kind:

```
  aaa                                 0
  aaaa                                0
  aaaaaand                            0
  aaaagggghhhh                        0
  aaas                                0
  aaawww                              1
```

I preprocessed with `removeWords, stopwords` but I would also like to remove words where the same letter is repeated four or more times. How can I do this in `tm_map`?

Comment: just a thought, but instead of removing the words, you might just remove the extra letters - that way you dont throw away data. any repeated leter 3+ times can remove the extra letter. tricky part is deciding whether you should keep 2 or 1. though not every letter in english ever had a double letter. u knowzzz?

Comment: hm, sure but i think for the moment I would just like to remove the "strange" words and see where the model ends up. how can I do that?

Comment: in r, i honestly cant help. i spend all my time with c/c++ and python. though i dont think it should be too difficult. you can just scan the document for tripple letters and remove the word. someone can correct me, but i dont think you can get much better than linear time complexity for something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You want to select just terms that match a regular expression, and subset the TermDocumentMatrix object accordingly.  So with your example:

```
require(tm)
txt <- "aaa aaaa aaaaaand aaaagggghhhh aaas aaawww"
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(VCorpus(VectorSource(txt)))
as.matrix(tdm[grep("(\\w)\\1{3,}", Terms(tdm)), ])
##               Docs
## Terms          1
##   aaaa         1
##   aaaaaand     1
##   aaaagggghhhh 1
```

In the regex, `\\1` is "backreference", referring to what is captured by the expression `\\w` between the brackets `(\\w)`, which stands for any word character.  (note: Your question said any two *letters* but if you meant any two *characters*, just substitute `(.)`.)  The `{3,}` asks for three or more of the same character as captured in the backreferences group.  The result: The regular expression matches any term that contains the same letter repeated four or more times.

Note: The `as.matrix()` is used here simply to display the object on the console so that we can see what terms are left.